# mariadb jdbc driver blob update not supported

Tags: jdbc, driver, mariadb

After I replaced mysql jdbc driver 5.1 with mariadb jdbc driver 1.1.5 and tested the existing code base that connected with MySQL Server 5.0 and MariaDB Server 5.2, everything works fine except a JDBC call to update a `blob` field in a table.

The blob field contains XML configuration file. It can be read out, and convert to xml and  insert some values.

Then convert it to ByteArrayInputStream object, and call the method

```
statement.updateBinaryStream(columnLabel, the ByteArrayInputStream object, its length)
```

but an exception is thrown:

> Perhaps you have some incorrect SQL syntax?
>   java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Updates are not supported
>     at
>   org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.getFeatureNotSupportedException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:165)
>     at
>   org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLResultSet.updateBinaryStream(MySQLResultSet.java:1642)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.updateBinaryStream(DelegatingResultSet.java:511)

I tried updateBlob method, the same exception was thrown.

The code works well with mysql jdbc driver 5.1.

Any suggestions on how to work around with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

See the ticket [updating blob with updateBinaryStream](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONJ-70), which in commnet states that it isn't supported.

A workaround would be to use two SQL statements. One which is used to select the data and other to update the data. Something like this:

```
final Statement select = connection.createStatement();
try {
    final PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement( "UPDATE table SET blobColumn=? WHERE idColumn=?" );
    try {
        final ResultSet selectSet = select.executeQuery( "SELECT idColumn,blobColumn FROM table" );
        try {
            final int id = selectSet.getInt( "idColumn" );

            final InputStream stream = workWithSTreamAndRetrunANew( selectSet.getBinaryStream( "blobColumn" ) ) );

            update.setBinaryStream( 1,stream );
            update.setInt( 2,id );
            update.execute();
        }
        finally {
            if( selectSet != null )
                selectSet.close();
        }
    }
    finally {
        if( update != null )
            update.close();
    }
}
finally {
    if( select != null )
        select.close();
}
```

But be aware that you need some information how to uniquely identify a table entry, in this example the column *idColumn* was used for that purpose. Furthermore is you stored empty stream in the 
database you might get an [SQLException](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONJ-77).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler work around is using binary literals (like X'2a4b54') and concatenation (UPDATE table SET blobcol = blobcol || X'2a4b54') like this:

```
int iBUFSIZ = 4096;
byte[] buf = new byte[iBUFSIZ];
int iLength = 0;
int iUpdated = 1;
for (int iRead = stream.read(buf, 0, iBUFSIZ);
     (iUpdated == 1) && (iRead != -1) && (iLength < iTotalLength);
     iRead = stream.read(buf, 0, iBUFSIZ))
{
    String sValue = "X'" + toHex(buf,0,iRead) + "'";
    if (iLength > 0)
        sValue = sBlobColumn + " || " + sValue;
    String sSql = "UPDATE "+sTable+" SET "+sBlobColumn+"= "+sValue;
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    iUpdated = stmt.executeUpdate(sSql);
    stmt.close();
}
```